# dotenv is undefined in express

Tags: node.js, express, dotenv

I have a `.env` file in my root directory that has `PORT=4000` inside

My `app.js` has the following code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

require('dotenv').config();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!!!');
  console.log(port);
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

But when I run the app with `nodemon app.js`, the `port` is 3000 instead of 4000. Why is my `.env` `PORT` variable undefined?

Comment: `require('dotenv').config();` put this on line one of your js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code solves the issue

```
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!!!');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You didnot require env before port variable. So you are getting 3000 instead of 4000. Just use this code. It will works fine.

```
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    require('dotenv').config();
    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.send('Hello World!!!');
      console.log(port);
    });
    
    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Comment: You didnot require env before port variable. So you are getting 3000 instead of 4000

Comment: Doing that gives me the following error: Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 4000;

Comment: Some porcess already using 4000 port. Find out the pid then kill that process. Then run you project again

Comment: I just deleted my project and tried your version and it worked. Guess something odd was going on with my deleted folder : /